# Is there a way of using something similar to natbib's \citenum in biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing

The `natbib` package provides the command `\citenum`, which returns just the number of the citation, unlike the typeset reference of `\cite`. Is a similar command available for `biblatex`?

Comment: Which style do you use?

Comment: @Bernard I use numeric-comp.

Comment: Isn't it the normal behaviour for citations commands?

Comment: @Bernard You mean the normal output in that style would be the number anyway? No, you get `[1]` instead of `1`. This `\citenum` is useful if you want a style-independent output, for example "See Ref~[\citenum{}]".

Comment: I see, I didn't get what you meant – I thought ypu obtained something more, such as the author.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Given that the `numeric-comp` style is used, it is possible to implement `\citenum` as follows:

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citenum}
  {}
  {\printfield{labelnumber}}
  {}
  {}
```

It can be use with other styles as well using the `labelnumber` package option.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{article1,
    author = {Author, First},
    title  = {Title 1},
    year   = 1993,
    month  = may,
    pages  = {10--15}
  }

  @inproceedings{article2,
    author = {Author, Second},
    booktitle  = {Conference Title},
    title  = {Article 2},
    year   = 1975,
    month  = aug,
    pages  = {120--125}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=authoryear,citecounter,natbib,labelnumber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{labelnumber}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\citenum}
  {}
  {\printfield{labelnumber}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}

\cite{article1}

\cite{article2}

\citenum{article1}

\citenum{article2}

\printbibliography  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To take into account every possible situation, I patched the original definition of the `\cite` command in `numeric-comp.cbx`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{article1,
    author = {Author, First},
    title = {Title 1},
    year = 1993,
    month = may,
    pages = {10--15}
  }

  @inproceedings{article2,
    author = {Author, Second},
    booktitle = {Conference Title},
    title = {Article 2},
    year = 1975,
    month = aug,
    pages = {120--125}
  }
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,citecounter,natbib,labelnumber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
%
\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\begin{document}

\cite{article1}

\cite{article2}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This does give just the number, but destroys the flexibility of `\cite` itself. The goal would be to still be able to flexibly change the citation style for the `\cite` command and at the same time have a style-independent command such as `\citenum` that gives a clean number.

Comment: Nothing prevents you from calling the ‘patched’ command `\citenum`. What I meant was to take take into account all possible cases, just as the original `\cite` does.

Comment: What do you mean by "all possible cases" here?

Comment: Well, I don't know exactly, because I do  not have at hand afile with `prenote` and `postnote`, but you see the definition of the `\cite` command is not so simple. I suppose it is such for a good reason, and I preferred to stck as close as poss[ble to the original definition, which begins with `\DeclareCiteCommand{\cite}[\mkbibbrackets]`, and decided to remove the `[\mkbibbrackets]` argument. It's the only modification.

Comment: Now I wonder whether there are any situations in which the solutions of @Guido and you differ. I guess his solution will always just be a number, whereas yours might adjust in some way to the context.

Comment: That was my initial idea. I think most generally, they will be the same, and his solution is really quite simple.

Comment: This solution works flawlessly with hyperref and compresses numbers automatically as well (the latter is not so easy with Guido's solution). Thanks!