# Create a modified cite command that colors the number inside the square brackets

Tags: biblatex, color, citing

I was searching and couldn't find an answer. I'm using the `cite{}` command and its working nicely ofc. I would like to make a small modification.
When my reference appears in the text, the reference number inside the square brackets should have a specified color.
How can I achieve this (please see attached picture below)?
Only the inner number should be colored and the outer brackets should stay black.
Any help is appreciated, thank you very much.

EDIT:
So far I'm using the following method to create my document.

[image: Like this]

```
% main tex-file
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, backref, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib/bibfile.bib}

\begin{document}
This is a test \cite{ref1}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}


% bib/bibfile.bib
@CONFERENCE{ref1,
  author = {Hans Neumann},
  title = {title},
  booktitle = {book title},
  year = {1998}
}
```

Comment: Posibly duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224568/different-style-color-for-some-specific-references-using-bibtex?rq=1

Comment: I'm primarily interested in colouring the reference numbers in my text and not necessarily in my list.

Comment: Should the citation callouts also be made into hyperlinks to the associated bib entries?

Comment: Can you please tell us which bibliography/citation package you are using? A solution for `biblatex` will be wildly different from a solution for `natbib`. The specific style you use also plays a role, so it would be great if you could show us a short example document (a so-called MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/) that reproduces the status quo. You may also want to clarify if you use `hyperref`. By default citations are usually linked with `hyperref` and if you give the correct options citations will automatically be coloured (though that colouring might not survive printing)

Comment: It would be easier to understand what you wanted if you added [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) to show what you are using bibtex or biblatex etc.

Comment: @moewe: thank you. I added some tex. This is what im currently using to generate my documents. Couldnt figure out so far how to change the content of the square brackets of a text reference.

Comment: Related, though not necessarily `biblatex`: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224568/different-style-color-for-some-specific-references-using-bibtex, https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/224596/different-style-color-for-some-specific-references-using-natbib

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref), which  has the added benefit of turning your citations etc into hyperlinks in the PDF file. By adding the lines

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=green}
```

to the end of your preamble ([hyperref](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/hyperref) likes being loaded last), your MWE produces:

[image]

although you pmight want a different shade of green:) Here is the full code:

```
% main tex-file
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, backref, sorting=none]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibfile.bib}

% to generate the bibfile
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}
@CONFERENCE{ref1,
  author = {Hans Neumann},
  title = {title},
  booktitle = {book title},
  year = {1998}
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks=true, citecolor=green}

\begin{document}
This is a test \cite{ref1}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

A big thank you to Andrew who posted an answer that solves my problem.

However, I also managed to get another solution as well (although Andrew's answer seems more elegant).
This question helped me: [Link](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/249118/is-there-a-way-of-using-something-similar-to-natbibs-citenum-in-biblatex/249123#249123)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{memoir}
\usepackage[style=numeric, backend=biber, backref, sorting=none, labelnumber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib/bibfile.bib}

% using labelnumber
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citenum}
  {}
  {\printfield{labelnumber}}
  {}
  {}

% defining a new custom command with desired color:
\newcommand\mycite[1]{[\textcolor{green}{\citenum{#1}}]}

\begin{document}
This is a test \mycite{ref1}.
% and i get the same output as Andrew! :D

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just another possibility, if using cite.sty and not hyperref

```
\renewcommand\citeform[1]{\textcolor{green}{#1}}
```

which will set the color of the numbers, and nothing else.